# Convergence of infinite product $\prod_{n=2}^\infty (1- \frac 1n) $

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, infinite-product

I am revising Complex Analysis and I am a bit confused. I have a couple of results from lectures which say that  $\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+a_n)$ converges if and only if the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(1+a_n) $ converges absolutely.

And also, the infinite product converges absolutely if and only if the $|a_n|$ are summable.

Consider the example:
$$\prod_{n=2}^\infty \left(1- \frac 1n\right) $$
It can easily be shown that the partial product $\prod_{n=2}^{N} (1- \frac 1n) = \frac 1N $ which tends to zero as $N\to \infty$

Maybe I'm interpreting the theorems wrong, but the sums:

$\sum_{n=2}^\infty |\log(1-\frac 1n)| $ and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |-\frac 1n| $ both diverge, so from the results I listed at the start, the product cannot converge, but it does - to zero.

I'm getting quite confused here so I would appreciate some help!

Comment: It diverges to zero.

Answer (score 6):

If partial products tends to zero as $N\to \infty$ we say that infinite product diverges to $0$.

Comment: Diverges to zero is an abuse of vocabulary. I understand why you (and few others) want to say it diverges to zero (the corresponding infinite sum diverges), but the sequence at the end of the day is $a_n = 1/n$. It is right to say that it converges to $0$, than diverges to $0$.

Comment: @user141421: Would you say that $\sum\frac1n$ converges to infinity?

Comment: @user141421 Yes the sequence of partial products converges and the infinite product diverges. There is no abuse here.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Would you say $\dfrac1n$ diverges to $0$?

Comment: @Did An infinite product is the limit of a sequence of partial products.

Comment: @user141421: You haven't answered my question.

Comment: @user141421 No kidding? For some easy exposition, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_product

Comment: @Did Just because someone on wikipedia writes it someway, should I accept. Are you even a mathematician? The interpretation of $$\prod_{n=2}^{\infty} \left(1-\dfrac1n\right)$$ is $\lim_{N \to \infty} a_N$, where $$a_N = \prod_{n=2}^{N} \left(1-\dfrac1n\right) = \dfrac1N$$
The right statement of the convergence criteria should read "The infinite product converges to a non-zero number iff the corresponding infinite sum converges."

Comment: @AsafKaragila The answer to your question is part in my question and above comment.

Comment: @AsafKaragila An even better question to ask you would be the following? Would you say $\exp(-\ln(n))$ diverges to $0$ or converges to $0$?

Comment: @user141421: My point was (although your reply to my question with other questions sort of ruined the process of getting there) that terms have context. In the context of products we say that something diverges to $0$, just like that in the context of the extended real line we say that something converges to $\infty$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila So you would say $0\cdot 0 \cdot 0 \cdots$ diverges to $0$? :)

Comment: @user141421: Again, we are talking about the context of products, in which we generally only talk about products of strictly positive numbers. If you wanna plug into the context things which are out of context, don't be surprised if the results are flustered mumbling and lack of definitive answers.

Comment: @user141421 No you are not supposed to accept something just because it is written on WP. In the present case though, it is written on WP **and** it happens to be explained in every textbook on infinite series and infinite products. (Last comment from me on this matter, I have little patience for your type.)

Comment: @AsafKaragila I am definitely talking in context. In fact, for the specific example $\prod_{n=2}^{N} (1-1/n)$, the product does indeed *converge* to zero. Also, where in the question has it been mentioned that the products are strictly positive numbers. Even if that is the case, the infinite product $\prod_{n=2}^{N} (1-1/n)$ *converges* to $0$ is right.

Comment: @user141421: No. You're taking the words "convergence" and "divergence" and you exploit the fact that these are used in *very closed* contexts, and very similar definitions. But the context itself is different. Here we talk about infinite products, there we talk about sequences. If you cannot accept that these are two **different** contexts, then I have nothing more to add to this conversation.

Comment: @Did Here is a proposition from Stein and Shakarchi. Page 141: "Proposition 3.1 If $\Sigma \vert a_n \vert < \infty$, then the product $\prod(1+a_n)$ converges. Moreover, the product *converges* to $0$ if and only if one of its factors is $0$." This never talks about convergence or divergence to zero, when the sum diverges. When the sum diverges, one needs to be careful as to what happens to the product and argue whether the product converges or diverges accordingly. Fanaticism in mathematics and sciences is worse than religious fanaticism.

Comment: @user141421: It is often said that when an infinite product of non-zero numbers is $0$, the product diverges, even though the sequence of partial products converges to $0$. This is not uncommon terminology and does not contradict the quote from Stein and Shakarchi since that statement is prefaced by $\sum|a_n|\lt0$. Given that preface, $\prod(1+a_n)$ can only be $0$ if $1+a_n=0$ for some $n$. (I would hate to contradict Stein since he was my graduate advisor :-)

Answer (score 2):

The right answer to your question is that the statement should read as follows:

> $\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+a_n)$ converges *to a non-zero real number* if and only if the sum $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty \log(1+a_n) $ converges absolutely.

As you have rightly observed the infinite product in your example does indeed *converge* to $0$. There are some people who would argue that the infinite product *diverges* to $0$, since the corresponding infinite sum diverges. However, this is incorrect, especially if you view the infinite product as
$$\displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^\infty (1+a_n) = \lim_{N \to \infty} b_N, \text{ where } b_N = \displaystyle\prod_{n=1}^N (1+a_n)$$

---

**EDIT** Also, to emphasize the fact that converging to zero is the right term to use, I quote the following proposition from Stein and Shakarchi. Page 141:

"Proposition $3.1$: If $\Sigma \left\vert a_n \right\vert < \infty$, then the product $\prod(1+a_n)$ converges. Moreover, the product **converges** to $0$ if and only if one of its factors is $0$."

Hence, converges to zero is the right term to use. When the sum diverges, one needs to be careful as to what happens to the product and argue whether the product converges to zero or diverges accordingly.

Comment: No, the product diverges to $0$ because $0$ does not belong to the topological group $\mathbb{C}^\times$. Infinite products are like infinite sums, well, they are infinite sums in (abelian) topological groups where you write the operation as multiplication. We say $\prod u_n$ converges if it converges in $\mathbb{C}^\times$. Then we make special conventions for products containing zero factors.

Comment: @DanielFischer Who cares? For this problem, I work over $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Here is a proposition from Stein and Shakarchi. Page 141: "Proposition 3.1 If $\Sigma \vert a_n \vert < \infty$, then the product $\prod(1+a_n)$ converges. Moreover, the product *converges* to $0$ if and only if one of its factors is $0$." This never talks about convergence or divergence to zero, when the sum diverges. When the sum diverges, one needs to be careful as to what happens to the product and argue whether the product converges or diverges accordingly.