# How to calculate this expression?(multiplication)

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, infinite-product

How do I show that for any starting $n$? (I am not really sure it is $0$, but I think it is).

$$\prod_{i=n}^\infty \left[1-\frac 1 i\right]=\prod_{i=n}^\infty \left[\frac{i-1}{i}\right]=0$$

I tried taking logarighm, then I get a sum. $\sum_{i=n}^\infty \ln\left(\frac{i-1}{i}\right)$. But then I must show that this sum goes to $-\infty$ can I show that in some way?

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778202/convergence-of-infinite-product-prod-n-2-infty-1-frac-1n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$\sum_{i=n}^\infty \log \frac{i-1}{i} = \sum_{i=n}^\infty (\log(i-1)-\log(i))=\lim_{N\to\infty} [\log(n-1)-\log(N)]$$

Comment: Very smart!, thanks!